# Linking dlib to Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, linker, dlib

I'm trying to link dlib to iOS project. I have generated a libdlib.a file and successfully added it to my project. When adding to Header Search Paths under build settings the directory of the dlib folder which is /Users/Christina/Desktop/ccvl/ios/EmoTrain/. When trying to build I get the following error:

*You should NOT add the dlib folder itself to your compiler's include path. 
  Doing so will cause the build to fail because of name collisions (such as 
  dlib/string.h and string.h from the standard library). Instead you should 
  add the folder that contains the dlib folder to your include search path 
  and then use include statements of the form #include  or
  #include "dlib/queue.h".*

This is exactly what I'm doing though, as the folder that contains dlib is EmoTrain.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, to clarify where dlib is, is queue.h in EmoTrain/queue.h or in EmoTrain/dlib/queue.h?

Comment: in EmoTrain/dlib/queue.h @TinyTheBrontosaurus

Answer (score 0):

There's two things to be sure of.

1) there is a "dlib" directory inside of the directory you are attaching
2) the project is not set to search recursively.

So if your header search path is "/Users/Christina/Desktop/ccvl/ios/EmoTrain/", and queue.h is "/Users/Christina/Desktop/ccvl/ios/EmoTrain/dlib/queue.h", then...double check your header search path is not "/Users/Christina/Desktop/ccvl/ios/EmoTrain/**".

I suppose a third thing to be sure of is you don't accidentally have the headers included in two different ways, the *other* of which might be backfiring on you. ;)